# Sensor Camera on Gazebo: Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, param-server, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i'm trying to create a sensor camera on [gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo), but i have this message on the terminal when i run the launch file:

```
[ERROR] [1323711066.531080823]: Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server
[ERROR] [1323711066.531205567]: Could not generate robot model
[ERROR] [1323711066.531238167]: Failed to extract kdl tree from xml robot description
[robot_state_publisher-4] process has died [pid 2161, exit code 255].
log files: /home/mauro/.ros/log/0edc0fb2-24e7-11e1-ba97-0016ea548718/robot_state_publisher-4*.log
```

i created a launch file:

```
<launch>

    <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" 
            args="$(find my_erratic)/worlds/my_world.world" output="screen" respawn="false" />

    <include file="$(find my_erratic)/launch/my_camera.launch" />
 
</launch>
```

the file my_camera.lauch is:

```
<launch> 
    <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
 
    <!-- send the camera XML to param server -->
    <param name="camera_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find my_erratic)/urdf/my_camera.urdf.xacro'" />
    
    <!-- push camera_description to factory and spawn camera in gazebo -->
    <node name="spawn_robot" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
          args="-param camera_description
                -urdf
                -x 2.5
                -z 2
                -P 90
                -model camera_description"
          respawn="false" output="screen" />
          
    <!-- start robot state publisher -->
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen" >
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
        <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="" />
    </node>          
          
</launch>
```

the file my_camera.urdf .xacro is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot
    xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
    xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
    xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface">
 
    <!-- Properties (Constants) -->   
    <property name="M_PI" value="3.14159"/>

    <!--                  Custom Finger Tip Camera                  -->


  <macro name="camera">
  
    <link name="camera_link">
     <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>  
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.001"/>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0001"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
            <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 -0.0005" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
  
    <joint name="finger_tip_camera_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <parent link="camera_link" />
      <child link="finger_tip_camera_link"/>
    </joint>            
    
    <link name="finger_tip_camera_link">        
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.01" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
        <inertia ixx="0.001"  ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"
                 iyy="0.001"  iyz="0.0"
                 izz="0.001" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    
  <gazebo reference="finger_tip_camera_link">
      <sensor:camera name="finger_tip_camera_sensor">
        <imageSize>640 480</imageSize>
        <imageFormat>R8G8B8</imageFormat>
        <hfov>90</hfov>
        <nearClip>0.01</nearClip>
        <farClip>100</farClip>
        <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
        <controller:gazebo_ros_camera name="finger_tip_camera_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
          <imageTopicName>finger_tip_cam/image</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>finger_tip_cam/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>finger_tip_camera_link</frameName>
          <interface:camera name="finger_tip_camera_iface" />
        </controller:gazebo_ros_camera>
      </sensor:camera>
      <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
      <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>        
    </gazebo>   
    
    <joint name="finger_tip_optical_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.2" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0.0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
      <parent link="finger_tip_camera_link" />
      <child link="finger_tip_optical_frame"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="finger_tip_optical_frame">
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.01" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
        <inertia ixx="0.001"  ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"
                 iyy="0.001"  iyz="0.0"
                 izz="0.001" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link> 
    
        <gazebo reference="camera_link">
            <material>Erratic/Yellow</material>
        </gazebo>       

        <gazebo reference="finger_tip_camera_link">
            <material>Erratic/Yellow</material>
        </gazebo>
        
        <gazebo reference="finger_tip_optical_frame">
            <material>Erratic/Yellow</material>
        </gazebo>   
    </macro>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12314/sensor-camera-on-gazebo:-could-not-find-parameter-robot_description-on-parameter-server/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`robot_state_publisher` looks for the parameter "robot_description" by default. The `robot_state_publisher` [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials) suggest that you use the following to change this:

```
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="rob_st_pub" >
  <remap from="robot_description" to="different_robot_description" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on 2011-12-12**:
i'm sorry! it doesn't work!

**Comment by [dvogureckiy99](https://answers.ros.org/users/101502/dvogureckiy99/) on 2023-02-17**:
It doesn't work.